# How to remove duplicate value from multidimensional array having different key

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to remove duplicate value from multidimensional array. I've tried many example but i am not getting as I want.

My array is here

```
Array
(
  [0] => Array
     (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [CouponCode] => REZEZ150
                [PurchaseAmt] => 1000.00
                [DiscountAmt] => 150.00
            )
        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [CouponCode] => REZEZ500
                [PurchaseAmt] => 2500.00
                [DiscountAmt] => 500.00
            )
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [CouponCode] => REZEZ150
                [PurchaseAmt] => 1000.00
                [DiscountAmt] => 150.00
            )
        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [CouponCode] => REZEZ350
                [PurchaseAmt] => 2000.00
                [DiscountAmt] => 350.00
            )
        [2] => stdClass Object
            (
                [CouponCode] => REZEZ500
                [PurchaseAmt] => 2500.00
                [DiscountAmt] => 500.00
            )
      )
     )
```

I want array after removing  duplicate value like

```
 Array
    (
      [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [CouponCode] => REZEZ150
                    [PurchaseAmt] => 1000.00
                    [DiscountAmt] => 150.00
                )
            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [CouponCode] => REZEZ350
                    [PurchaseAmt] => 2000.00
                    [DiscountAmt] => 350.00
                )
            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [CouponCode] => REZEZ500
                    [PurchaseAmt] => 2500.00
                    [DiscountAmt] => 500.00
                )
          )
         )
```

similar question with answer but not solve my case:

```
[How to remove duplicates from multidimensional array in php \[duplicate\]][1]
```

Comment: i think there is a problem while fetching data, can you explain little bit more how are you fetching data from your db??

Comment: actually i am sending  request in foreach loop  and getting response one by one  after that append in array Like $response[$key] and print it out of loop;

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$arrResult = $arrResult1 = array();

foreach($arrData as $key1 => $arrData1){
    foreach($arrData1 as $key2 => $arrData2){
                $arrResult[] = $arrData2;
    }
}

$arrResult1[] = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $arrResult)));

echo "<pre>"; print_r($arrResult1);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but its not working like as i want

Answer (score 0):

Thank You 
I have solved it
Firstly i changed it in to single dimensional  array like

```
 $a =    Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [CouponCode] => REZEZ150
            [PurchaseAmt] => 1000.00
            [DiscountAmt] => 150.00
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [CouponCode] => REZEZ500
            [PurchaseAmt] => 2500.00
            [DiscountAmt] => 500.00
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [CouponCode] => REZEZ150
            [PurchaseAmt] => 1000.00
            [DiscountAmt] => 150.00
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [CouponCode] => REZEZ350
            [PurchaseAmt] => 2000.00
            [DiscountAmt] => 350.00
        )

    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [CouponCode] => REZEZ500
            [PurchaseAmt] => 2500.00
            [DiscountAmt] => 500.00
        )

)
```

after that run foreach loop behalf of KEY AND VALUE Like

```
$j=array();     

foreach ($a as $key => $value) {
    $j[$value->CouponCode]['CouponCode']=$value->CouponCode;
    $j[$value->CouponCode]['PurchaseAmt']=$value->PurchaseAmt;
    $j[$value->CouponCode]['DiscountAmt']=$value->DiscountAmt;
}

p($j);
```

And now i got result

```
Array
(
    [REZEZ150] => Array
        (
            [CouponCode] => REZEZ150
            [PurchaseAmt] => 1000.00
            [DiscountAmt] => 150.00
        )

    [REZEZ500] => Array
        (
            [CouponCode] => REZEZ500
            [PurchaseAmt] => 2500.00
            [DiscountAmt] => 500.00
        )

    [REZEZ350] => Array
        (
            [CouponCode] => REZEZ350
            [PurchaseAmt] => 2000.00
            [DiscountAmt] => 350.00
        )

)
```

Please just suggest me is it good way or not ?

Comment: While you are at it when looping to create the one dimension array, simply check if the element already exist. This will avoid you the second loop and get uou the unduplicated array you need.

Answer (score 0):

Use `array_filter()`:

```
$couponCodes = array();

$a = array_filter($a, function (stdClass $purchase) use (&$couponCodes) {
    if (in_array($purchase->CouponCode, $couponCodes)) {
        return false;
    }

    $couponCodes[] = $purchase->CouponCode;

    return true;
});
```

Follows https://stackoverflow.com/a/34506942/1172545.

For reference, see http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php.